# Does LineageOS provide "Zip Signature Verification"

Tags: twrp, lineageos, zip, signature-error

TWRP provides an option on boot for "Zip signature verification". Is that option part of Android ROM packaging and would LineageOS support it? For me, that option does

```
Checking for Digest file...
Skipping Digest check: no Digest file found
verifying zip signature...
Zip signature verification failed!
Error installing zip file '/data/lineageos_updates/lineage-nightly-n1awifi-signed.zip'
Updating partition details...
...done
```

I ask this because this ROM was download with the OTA update from LineageOS, and when it failed I download a new ROM from the website and it also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! LineageOS does not Zip Signature Verify, instead the LineageOS download site provides SHA256 codes which the user or the downloading app can use to verify their downloads (using a tool like `sha256sum`).

---

You can click on the `sha256` link above and change the `?sha256` in the url to `?sha1sum` for example make this

https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/full/guacamole/20191212/lineage-16.0-20191212-nightly-guacamole-signed.zip?sha256

Look like this,

https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/full/guacamole/20191212/lineage-16.0-20191212-nightly-guacamole-signed.zip?sha1

---

You can [verify build authenticity](https://wiki.lineageos.org/verifying-builds.html) by checking the signature,

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -printcert -jarfile lineage-build-signed.zip
```